# Django mptt join/merge models

Tags: python, django, django-mptt, mptt

I have this two models:

```
class Folder(MPTTModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    parent = TreeForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, related_name='children')
    position = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    class MPTTMeta:
        order_insertion_by = ['position']

class Page(MPTTModel):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    file_content = models.TextField()
    parent = TreeForeignKey(Folder, null=False, blank=False, related_name='page', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I have been trying and trying, but I can't find any solution.

Is there anyway to merge those two models in just one tree diagram?
The idea is that a Folder can contain a Folder or a Page

I'm using django 1.6.5 and python3

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should create an abstract superclass. Then you can have this class from which both (folder and Page) inherit and you can define the parent relation already in there.